# Closed-form for $B=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{a_1=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_1^2}\sum_{a_2=1}^{a_1}\frac{1}{a_2^2}\cdots\sum_{a_n=1}^{a_{n-1}}\frac{1}{a_n^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, recreational-mathematics

### Introduction

This problem came to my mind few years ago when I first learned about limits and infinite sums. I saw sums, double sums, triple sums etc, but never an infinite sum basically an infinite chain of summation symbols which will converge to a real value. So I constructed the expression below,

### My Question

**Is there a closed form of the following number-**

$\textstyle\displaystyle{B=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{a_1=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_1^2}\sum_{a_2=1}^{a_1}\frac{1}{a_2^2}\cdots\sum_{a_n=1}^{a_{n-1}}\frac{1}{a_n^2}}$

Or some more easier representations not involving this infinite chain of sigma symbols with only finite amount of indices? Does it even converge?

### Details And Observation

Let's first define a double sequence for which will converge to $B$.

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\Sigma_{m,n}=\sum_{a_1=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_1^2}\sum_{a_2=1}^{a_1}\frac{1}{a_2^2}\cdots\sum_{a_m=1}^{a_{m-1}}\frac{1}{a_m^2}}$

So, $B=\Sigma_{\infty,\infty}$

A list of a few terms would be

[$\Sigma_{1,\infty}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D)$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$

[$\Sigma_{2,\infty}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D)$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\frac{7\pi^4}{360}}$

[$\Sigma_{3,100}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bj%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C1%2Ck%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C100%7D%5D)$\textstyle\displaystyle{=1.95233691...}$

[$\Sigma_{4,36}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bj%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bm%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2Cj%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C1%2Ck%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C36%7D%5D)$\textstyle\displaystyle{=1.93916539...}$

[$\Sigma_{5,28}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bk%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bj%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bm%2C2%5D%5DSum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2Cm%7D%5D%2C%7Bm%2C1%2Cj%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C1%2Ck%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C28%7D%5D)$\textstyle\displaystyle{=1.92936096...}$

$\vdots$

I can't get more values for this, Wolfram Alpha doesn't work.

Notice that $\Sigma_{m,n}$ satisfies a recurrence relation-

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\Sigma_{m,n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\Sigma_{m-1,k}}{k^2}}$

Where, $\Sigma_{0,n}=1$

This recurrence relation is very similar to [Hyperharmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperharmonic_number), it just has a factor of $k^{-2}$ within the sum and the initial value is different. The hyperharmonic numbers satisfies

$\textstyle\displaystyle{H_n^{(r)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}H_k^{(r-1)}}$

Beyond this observation I am clueless.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let us define

$$\Sigma_{\infty,n} = \lim_{m\to\infty} \Sigma_{m,n}$$

It can be proven using simple induction that $\Sigma_{m,1}=1$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$, hence we have that $\Sigma_{
\infty,1}=1$. Now, from your recurrence relation, taking the limit of both sides as $m\to\infty$, we have

$$\Sigma_{\infty,n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\Sigma_{\infty,k}}{k^2}=\Sigma_{\infty,n-1}+\frac{\Sigma_{\infty, n}}{n^2}$$

which may be solved for $\Sigma_{\infty,n}$, yielding

$$\Sigma_{\infty, n}=\frac{\Sigma_{\infty, n-1}}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}$$

Now, since we already have that $\Sigma_{\infty, 1}$, we obtain the following formula by induction:

$$\Sigma_{\infty, n} = \prod_{k=2}^n \Big(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\Big)^{-1}$$

which gives us the desired result:

$$\color{green}{\Sigma_{\infty,\infty} = \prod_{k=2}^\infty \Big(1-\frac{1}{k^2}\Big)^{-1} = 2}$$

which is supported by your numerical evidence, showing values $\approx 1.9$.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Haha, I wasn't expecting it to work out so nicely given how complicated the problem looks! :D

Comment: @metamorphy Oops, thanks for fixing that :)